# Need assistance regarding UITableViewCell SeparatorInset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

1> I have `UITableViewCell` and `UITableViewCell subclass cell` both in my tableview. Setting `SeparatorInset` on `UITableViewCell subclass cell` is not working?, but If I set it on `UITableViewCell` it works fine.

2> Apple doc regarding `SeparatorInset` says:

> You can use this property to add space between the current cell’s
>   contents and the left and right edges of the table. Positive inset
>   values move the cell content and cell separator inward and away from
>   the table edges. Negative values are treated as if the inset is set to
>   0.
>
> Only the left and right inset values are respected; the top and bottom
>   inset values are ignored. The value assigned to this property takes
>   precedence over any default separator insets set on the table view.

a. If I set `[cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 0)];` on `UITableViewCell` it push the content towards right

but setting `[cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 100)];` on `UITableViewCell` push only separator towards left not the content, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**

In `UITableViewCell` you have subviews which position you cannot edit directly (title, accessoryView, ...). Here comes `separatorInset` which enables you to adjust position of those subviews (in other words `separatorInset` is considered during position calculation of those subviews).

In custom `UITableViewCell` subclass you are positioning your own subviews, so unless you specifically consider `separatorInset` during calculation of their position, it has no effect.

**2)**

`separatorInset` does not 'push' the content to left/right, rather adds (virtual) insets to container in which they are positioned. So if e.g. you only have title that does not stretch to full width of the cell (-100) you would not see any difference after adding right inset.

Comment: thanks for such detail answer, but please can you tell me how you find all this info, its not specified in Apple docs.

Comment: Trial and error for 1) and common semantics of 'inset' througouth cocoa for 2)